# Data mapping without coding

Tags: java, json, mapping, integration, analytics

What is the fastest way to **construct target messages from source messages by mapping file**?

Such integration tasks are usual for business applications, but i dont know any *universal approach* for it. Coding them with *objects mapping libs* (like [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) or [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/)) - its wasting developer time, its mindless routine, isn't so?

This work can be successfully done by analyst: create any *simple data mapping in json*, send to integration service and check target message format.
But for this purpose i've found only big and not-free solutions like Altova [MapForce](https://www.altova.com/mapforce) (modeler&server) or IBM Integration Bus [data graphical editor](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/cm28851_.htm).

How do you solve such tasks in your projects?

**UPDATE**

Mapping format, we choosed for our issue (incl. *nesting, arrays, rules*):

```
{
  "camunda.Form": {
    "blockA": {
      "FullName": "QuestionareResEntity.FullName.data",
      "RTOPA1TF": "QuestionnaireResEntity.ResTypeOfPaymentAgents.data || CONTAIN || ID1",
      "RTOPA2TF": "QuestionnaireResEntity.ResTypeOfPaymentAgents.data || YOUR_RULE || Param1,Param2,Param3",
    },
    "blockB": {
      "ColExMan": "InfoAboutGovernment.CollegialExecutiveManagement.data || DICT || CollegialExecutiveManagementDictionary"
    },
    "LEResColManag.row[].cells": {
      "FName": "TableLERes3[].FullName.data",
      "Citiz": "TableLERes3[].Citizenship.data",
      "RegAddress": "TableLERes3[].RegistrationAdress.data",
    }
  }
}
```

How does it seem for you by convenience and readability?

Appreciate your thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Don't think there is any library/tool for this; but it can be easily written in a dynamic language like groovy, JS etc.

Comment: Hello, @SatyendraKumar, thanks. See my comment below for Chris, please.

Comment: @SatyendraKumar, vote for reopen, please, if you think so

Comment: @ChrisF, i've edited the post after reading advices of help center - can it be reopen, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON to XML by free automatic converters. Then use the classic way with XSLT and XPath on the converted XML to convert the data in a similar way as you have listed. A lot of free tools, graphical editors and librarys are out there for XML.

Comment: Hi, Chris, thanks. Ok, so it must be a piece of code, yes? 
Will it be written once or every time for new mapping? If it will be written once - so the solution is library / service. I cannot believe that such lib (good tested) doesn´t exist yet. **Or**, it can be, that other developers solve such tasks by another way! That's what about my question.

Comment: @DanBrandt Somehow you must give the rules and tell the names of the JSON output properties, like in your example above. If you consider this as a piece of code, then yes. I consider the program as code that does the transformation, not the ruleset (XSLT) itself. This XSLT will take your XML-input and transform it to the wanted JSON. In other words: The same XSLT can take different input data and produce different output data accordingly, no need to change the XSLT every time. But if you want to change the rules, then of course you must change the XSLT.

Comment: @DanBrandt About other ways: if the rules are not complicated, then you could record a word-macro (or a macro in notepad++ or any other capable editor) with simple find/replace commands inside and run it on your JSON. No coding knowledge needed, but regular-expression-knowlege for your replace-commands will be very helpful to solve more complicated replacements. I did that several times to transform data when migrating from an old to a new system.

Comment: thank you for answers - with your help i've found JOLT (https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) lib - "xslt for json". It's powerfull for such tasks. Maybe will be helpful for you too